# Cálculo de total Javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, este é o código que faz o cálculo do meu carrinho de compras, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando atualiza a página no navegador, volta ao preço inicial. Ou seja, se adicionar 2 produtos ele exibe direito, mas quando ha um refresh do navegador, ele volta para uma quantidade, como posso resolver ?

```
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('input').change(function (e) {
        id = $(this).attr('rel');
        $index = this.value;
        $preco = $('font#preco'+id).html().replace("R$ ",'');
        console.log($preco);
        $val = ($preco*$index).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');;
        $('font#sub'+id).html('R$ '+$val);
          });
        });
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar Cookies? geralmente esses dados ficam salvo em sessão do lado servidor.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** é interpretado e executado pelo browser e a cada nova execução do browse o javascript é recarregado com seus valores predefinidos.

Como salvar os dados e, mesmo com refresh obter-se os valores novamente?

> **Sessão** é um recurso que permite que você salve valores (variáveis) para serem usados ao longo da visita do usuário. Valores salvos na sessão podem ser usados em qualquer parte do script, mesmo em outras páginas do site. São variáveis que permanecem setadas até o visitante fechar o browser ou a sessão ser destruída.

### Javascript:

```
...
    <script> 
    localStorage.setItem('chave','valor');

    alert(localStorage.getItem('chave'));
    </script>
...
```

### PHP:

Você precisa iniciar a sessão antes de poder setar ou pegar valores dela. Não há limite de valores salvos na sessão. A sessão é pessoal de cada visitante. Quando um visitante acessa o site, é gerado um cookie no computador dele informando um id único de sessão e o PHP usa esse identificador pra ‘organizar’ as sessões entre os visitantes do seu site. Mas esse cookie tem validade apenas enquanto o browser estiver aberto.

- Para abrir a sessão é só usar esse comando no PHP:

..

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
```

- Depois de iniciada a sessão você pode definir valores dentro dela dessa forma:

..

```
<?php
$_SESSION['preco'] = 100;
```

- E quando você precisar exibir o valor salvo na sessão (provavelmente em outras páginas), é só fazer assim:

..

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['preco']; // Resultado: 100
```

- Você pode salvar quantos valores quiser, pode re-definir os valores e usa-los em echos, argumentos de funções e da forma que preferir.
  Para deletar uma variável específica da sessão você usa o unset():

..

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['preco']); // Deleta uma variável da sessão
```

- Você também pode destruir toda a sessão de uma só vez, eliminando todas as variáveis salvas nela:-

..

```
<?php
session_destroy(); // Destrói toda sessão
```

### Documentação Oficial:

Função [session_start()](http://br.php.net/session_start) » Inicia a sessão

Função [unset()](http://us.php.net/unset) » Deleta uma variável do PHP

Função [session_destroy()](http://us.php.net/session_destroy) » Destrói toda uma sessão e suas variáveis